# Anybody have a workaround for gdb hanging while rendering pretty print in eclipse?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, pretty-print

I've updated to eclipse neon, I svn updated to the latest 
svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python, and I've just built gdb 7.12.1, all the latest stuff, doesn't help.

I have the pretty printing all working, but every once in a while, trying to update the variables view, gdb will hang. Actually it spins the cpu. I've attached gdb to gdb (because I find the idea amusing) and have gotten a number of stack traces and they're all implying some failure to find a printer and retrying over and over. Anybody ever see this or have a workaround? It's not obvious which printer (if it's a single one) is causing the problem, or I'd just disable it.

Suggestions on how to even diagnose what printer to disable?
I google and google and nobody complains of this behaviour, but having reinstalled everything, I don't get why it's not happening to anybody else.

ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I would suggest posting the stack traces to the [gdb mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/).

Comment: check whether it working outside eclipse i.e gdb CLI. If it is working there then I feel it is gdb configuration commands. Post the code you tried with so that others can debug and verify

Comment: the problem is it doesn't happen consistently, I can't force it to happen in such a confined test that I can then try it in gdb from the command line. But I will post stack traces to the gdb mailing list thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when you have a breakpoint before an std container like *list* is initialized (but it is in the stack frame).

The problem is that the pretty-printer is trying to iterate over the non-initialized list and throws an exception (can't access memory) when looking at an item of the list.

`gdb` tries to push ahead and display the next item, but the Python pretty-printer is not able to move to the next item, as the *Next* pointer is not accessible. In the MI implementation there is no limit to the number of times this will be repeated, so effectively hangs `gdb`.

As workaround, set a breakpoint past all the std containers initialization.